# Passing in String from an HTML form to a Python not working

Tags: python, html, forms, cgi

**What is supposed to happen:** I am running this python program on Flask and am trying to return the "file_name" from the HTML form to my python script so that I can use it in another python function. (Ex. If I submit "myFile" in the box that says "File Name:" in the form, I want my HTML script to send "myFile" to my python script correctly.

**Problem:** When I run my script and submit a string to the HTML form ("file_name") and ask my python script to return this value, it will return "None". I tried changing this to a POST request and that also did not solve the issue.

**On the HTML Page:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>
Your Form
</title>

</head>
    <body>
            <form action ="/start/" method="GET" accept-charset="UTF-8">
                File Name: <input type ="text" name="file_name"> <br />
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
            </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

**The Python Script I'm connecting it to:**

```
import cgi

app = Flask(__name__)
form = cgi.FieldStorage()

@app.route('/start/', methods = ["GET"])
def Initiate():
    your_file_name = form.getvalue('file_name')
    return your_file_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `your_file_name = form.getvalue('file_name')`, try this:

`your_file_name = request.get_json('file_name')`

Also, change `<form action ="/start/" method="GET" accept-charset="UTF-8">` to this:

```
<form action="/start/" mimetype='application/json' method="GET" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

This will give you a JSON response which you can parse with key-value pairs. If you haven't already, make sure you're importing request from flask:

`from flask import request`

Comment: I tried your suggestion and got this: " Bad Request Failed to decode JSON object: No JSON object could be decoded". Do you know why?

Comment: Try deleting name='submit' from your submit button. Also, when you're on the webpage, right click -> inspect -> Console (top of the window that came up). Check out the error message there. What does it say?

Additionally, you could try this: your_file_name = request.get_json     \n  
   file_name = your_file_name['file_name']